# Shall we [resolve] to burn this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolve) currently has the tag wiki

> Domain name resolvers determine the appropriate domain name servers responsible for the domain name in question by a sequence of queries starting with the right-most (top-level) domain label.
>
> The mechanism in this simple form would place a large operating burden on the root servers, with every search for an address starting by querying one of them.
>
> Being as critical as they are to the overall function of the system, such heavy use would create an insurmountable bottleneck for trillions of queries placed every day. In practice caching is used in DNS servers to overcome this problem, and as a result, root nameservers actually are involved with very little of the total traffic.

Both the wiki and the tag itself seem rather useless to me. Programming questions about resolving DNS should be tagged [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns). Questions about resolving DNS that aren't programming-related shouldn't be on SO at all.

Currently, this tag is being used for 506 questions, relatively few of which even have anything to do with DNS and several of which aren't on-topic for SO at all. Topics include:

- Android Studio failing to resolve a library's name
- The video editing software package DaVinci Resolve (off-topic for SO entirely.)
- The user's browser failing to resolve a domain name (off-topic for SO entirely.)
- Resolving a multiple promise request in jQuery.
- Resolving Webpack module names.
- Resolving .Net assemblies.
- Resolving Google Cloud Storage objects.

There are also occasionally questions that are actually about resolving DNS, but I don't see how the [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolve) tag makes that any more clear than just the [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) tag, since resolving names is literally the whole point of DNS.

Using [Shog's criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied and is it unambiguous?**

   It usually does have *something* to do with the questions to which it is being applied, but it's certainly not unambiguous (given that it's being used to mean several different things.)
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Some of them are, others aren't. The topic described in the tag wiki *can* be on-topic for SO (if it's a question about programming something to resolve DNS,) but it's not *necessarily* on-topic (if it's a question about using a program that is resolving DNS.)
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   I would argue that it does not in the case of DNS resolution. [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) seems like it should be sufficient. Name resolution is the whole point of DNS. And [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) is certainly *far* more descriptive of what the question is about than [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolve).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Definitely not, as evidenced by it being used with numerous different meanings and a minority of questions appearing to be about the meaning described in the tag wiki.

Shall we resolve to burn [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolve)?

Comment: I agree with this burnination. It's not clear to me how the topics in the tag wiki are on topic here at all - they seem more like Server Fault questions. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @EJoshuaS Yeah, the wiki isn't really programming-related at all. Questions about DNS could be on-topic at SO, SF, or SU depending on the context, but SO already has the [tag:dns] tag for that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If the [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) tag doesn't only apply to DNS resolution, then it could be renamed to [dns-resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns-resolve) or [dns-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns-resolution); but in any case, [resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolve) by itself is far too ambiguous to remain. I support burnination.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that [tag:dns-resolution] would be much better if such a tag were needed, though I'd argue that there's not really much you can do with DNS other than resolve things. That's kind of the point of DNS, so a [tag:dns-resolution] tag would seem a little redundant to me.